I have a problem while building my flutter project with fvm
When i'm running an empty project everything works perfectly but when I try to run an existing one I have the error :
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This is linked with that thread: how to solve Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug', but nothing said here has worked for me.
I've already tried:

Deleting my .gradle

Deleting the Flutter SDK

Changing to a different Java version (I tried java 11 and java 17)

run flutter clean

run flutter update

run flutter pub cache repair

run flutter pub clean


Could this be related to fvm and not flutter directly?

Hey, you did not even edit my comment in Staging ground to specify which Java versions you tried.

Hey, yes my bad. Fixed it.
